# how to extract content from another content using Javascript

Tags: javascript

my String is:

```
var str = "<footnote xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"><para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para></footnote>"
```

I want to store the contents which is inside the footnote tag in another variable, I need a string function to slove this,

**Note**: the values of `xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"` may come as single digit or double digit.

Can someone give any Idea for this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like:

```
var str = '<footnote xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"><para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para></footnote>';

var match, 
    res = "", 
    pattern = /<footnote[^>]*>(.*?)<\/footnote>/ig;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {   
  res += match[1]; 
}
console.log(res); //<para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para>
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7323/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can help:

```
$(str).html();
$(yourAnotherFoornotVar).find('para').html()
```

You can put a html string into the jQuery selector, without really having that element in your page.

Comment: Dear Chris, I need in javascript but thank you so much for your swift reply and its helpful

Answer (score 1):

newStr will hold whatever is in inside footernote, no need of jQuery for this.

```
var str = '<footnote xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"><para aid:pstyle="Copytext">„Muchacho“ (1924), Musik: Luis N. Visca, Text: Celedonio Esteban Flores.</para></footnote>';
var newStr = str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1, (str.indexOf('>')-10));
console.log(newStr); // xml:id="ch03-fn-5" label="5"
```